# Yii - How to use a class inside config/main?

Tags: php, yii

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
                'gii'=>'gii',
                'gii/<controller:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
                'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',
                '(' . implode('|', EventType::$TYPES_TO_URL) . ')' => 'home/index',
```

In the code above, I try to use a static variable of `EventType` class, to create a regex for urlManager's rules. But I get the errors:

```
Warning: include(EventType.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/trmop/Sites/test.dev/Yii-1-1-14/YiiBase.php on line 427

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'EventType.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.19/lib/php') in /Users/trmop/Sites/test.dev/Yii-1-1-14/YiiBase.php on line 427

Fatal error: Class 'EventType' not found in /Users/trmop/Sites/test.dev/app/config/main.php on line 72
```

It seems that Yii has not loaded the classes yet.

I could do `include(dirname(__FILE__) . '../../models/EventType.php');`, but it does not seem a clean solution.

Is there a better way to do it using Yii's features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this can help you out.

[Register Autoloader](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#registerAutoloader-detail)

Also you can import your class

```
import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),
```

Comment: How do you suggest `registerAutoloader()` be used here?